# Change div content dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-manipulation

I'm wondering how I can change the html content of a div.

This is the starting point:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="fruits">apple</div>
    <div class="fruits">banana</div>
    <div class="fruits">strawberry</div>
</div>
```

Output on page:

apple
banana
strawberry

The output should be changed to:

cat
dog
fish
...or something like this.

I guess I have to iterate over the class "fruits" with .each() or something.
I know how to change single elements or content of a single div, but i don't understand how that works when you have the same class for multiple times.

class="fruits"
class="fruits"
class="fruits"
....

Hope you can help.

Comment: Where are you storing your Animals strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### JavaScript

```js
const items = ["cat", "dog", "fish"];

document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((el, i) => {
  el.textContent = items[i];
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">banana</div>
  <div class="item">strawberry</div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
var animals = ["cat", "dog", "fish"];

$(".fruits").text(function(i){
  return animals[i];
});
```

Store your animals into an Array,
Loop with the `.text()` callback over your `.fruits` selector, and modify the text by returning the index of the `animals` that matches the current index `i` (`animals[i]`).

In case you have more selectors elements than the Array length you can modulo the result using: `return animals[i%animals.length];`

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rafate/1/edit?html,js,output)***

---

Since it's not clear where you're storing your Animals strings,
you can use also this simple example to achieve what you need and that's using `data-*` attribute:

```
<div class="fruits" data-to="cat">apple</div>
<div class="fruits" data-to="dog">banana</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".fruits").text(function(i){
  return $(this).data().to;     // or use: // this.dataset.to;
});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rafate/2/edit)***

Answer (score 3):

> **Roko** provided an answer in jQuery, with that out of the way..

There is no need to use jQuery for such a simple task, here is one in **plain JavaScript**. ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tqdyd87r/))

```
var pets = [ "cat", "dog","fish" ];
var fruits = document.querySelectorAll(".fruits"); // Partial support in IE8
for( var i = 0 ; i < fruits.length ; i ++ )
    fruits[i].innerHTML = pets[i];
```

Here is an even faster version by [**@Roko**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan).

```
var pets = [ "cat", "dog", "fish" ],
    fruits = document.getElementsByClassName("fruits"), // Not supported in IE8
    tot = fruits.length,
    i = 0;
for(;i<tot;) fruits[i].innerHTML = pets[i++];
```

[**Benchmark jQuery vs JavaScript vs Roko's JavaScript**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-javascript/2/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, jQuery *is* JavaScript, and inside the Sizzle function `selector` it already uses the JS's (guess what!) `querySelectorAll` to create a collection of Elements objects and all it takes is `$(".fruits")`

Comment: I never said jQuery *wans't* javascript, I said my answer is in plain javascript (no libraries), I also pointed out that you gave an answer in jQuery, so that my answer only counts as an addition or another solution to the problem. I believe my answer is more efficient, while being somewhat more tedious to write :)

Comment: JS will be always faster than jQ, agreed with that, but jQ will help you move with your project and don't care about IE8's partial support of `querySelector / querySelectorAll`

Comment: No doubt! jQuery serves as a great polyfill, but it's overused in my opinion, that's why I provided a jQuery-free solution :)

Comment: here, I've create a JS version that runs double faster than yours: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-javascript/2 (since you're interested in JS versions ;) ) Might be useful! Cheers

Comment: I thought about it, but I went to a more logic-friendly loop haha, I've added your version, thanks! :)

Comment: (The fancy `++` loop  is just there cause I was bored) The main speed difference came out cause the use of  `getElementsByClassName` :)

Comment: Ahh, yes I was curious about that, I'm doing a jsperf test for all the "getElementBy" methods! Thanks for the inspiration haha :)

Comment: Created an even faster one: (same Benchmark link /2 ) But again note that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported at all in IE8 :)

Comment: 5% faster by not defining/getting variables inside the loop, interesting, that's pretty cool haha

Comment: Exactly. P.S: sorry for my edit/intrusion. Just added the notes about IE8 compatibility and the newest JS code. See ya

Comment: No problem, always what's best for the asker!

Answer (score 1):

Using .each would look something like this. I've set it to toggle back and forth using an array to hold the other collection. However, Roko C. Buljan's answer accomplishes essentially the same thing with less effort by avoiding some unnecessary method calls, so I would definitely say his is the better answer.

```js
var otherVals = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'];

function go() {
  $('.fruits').each(function(index) {
    var temp = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(otherVals[index]);
    otherVals[index] = temp;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="fruits">apple</div>
  <div class="fruits">banana</div>
  <div class="fruits">strawberry</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="go()" />
```

Comment: `$('.fruits')` is already a collection of elements. No need to `.each()` to modify the `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: Your way is more concise. I'll add a note about it.